# Predicate Is Not Filtering Through Data Properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to display the count of objects from my fetch controller in my cell's badgeString.

For some reason, the badge is staying the same for all cells, and not adjusting for each.

`Indexpath.row ==2`  is for last week and `Indexpath.row == 3` is for last month.
In my cell configuration, I have:

```
if (indexPath.row > 1)
{
    cell.badgeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]count]];
}
```

This is my fetch controller method:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] ;
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
NSDate *thisWeek  = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0];
NSDate *thisMonth = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -2629743.83]; // Use NSCalendar for

if (indexPath.row ==2)
{
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", thisWeek, today]];
}
else if (indexPath.row ==3)
{
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", thisMonth, today]];
}
```

Full Fetch Controller Code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] ;
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
    NSDate *thisWeek  = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -604800.0];
    NSDate *thisMonth = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -2629743.83]; // Use NSCalendar for

    if (indexPath.row ==2)
    {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", thisWeek, today]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row ==3)
    {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", thisMonth, today]];
    }

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    NSLog(@"Number of Objects = %i",
           [[__fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);
    return __fetchedResultsController;
    NSLog(@"Number of Objects = %i",
          [[__fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);

}
```

Code For Cell Configuration:

```
- (void)configureCell:(TDBadgedCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if (indexPath.row > 1)
        {
            cell.badgeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]count]];
        }
```

Comment: Without seeing the parameters to your methods it is hard to debug.  Are you updating the fetchedResultsController every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called?  I've never used that controller, but it looks like you're expecting it to be called with each cell being created/reused and it isn't.

Comment: Hmm i guess I need to update the fetched results controller every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.  Any idea how to do so?

Comment: You should run the fetches externally to the tableview methods and store the results in an NSArray.  Table view then just uses the array to display the information.  If you don't do this scrolling will be very very very slow.

Comment: Thanks, I am running the fetch externally.  I am using Apple's NSFetchResultsControllor Delegate methods.

Comment: If you showed the parameters to your fetch method and where you were calling it from it would help greatly.

Comment: Thanks Michael, what are you referring to by the parameters?  I just added the full fetch code to my question.

Comment: You are creating a 0,0 `indexPath` then later checking for row 2 or row 3.  You would need to pass the indexPath into the method - right now it will always be 0,0 and the results will never change.  Note however that if you call this method directly from you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method your scrolling will be horribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) refreshTableData {
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
...
NSArray *fetchResults = [first predicate call goes here];
[results addObject:fetchResults];
fetchResults = [second predicate call goes here];
[results addObject:fetchResults];
...
[tableview reloadData];
}
```